# How do I send all my form data at once with Zapier?

Tags: zapier, webflow

I have a big webflow form that I want to send to one of my clients with zapier but I can only select individual form values but is their a way to send them all at once?

I triend finding something on google but didn't find anything.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.